# How to close a UserControl properly in WPF MVVM and release memory?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using the navigation in my WPF MVVM project. I have the following UserControl:

```
<UserControl>
    //Some codes
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:SfDataPagerBehavior_OnDemand />
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</UserControl>
```

and

```
public class SfDataPagerBehavior_OnDemand : Behavior<EquipmentIdentitySetting>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        //Some codes
        //Data is loaded to Datagrid
    }
    protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnAssociatedObject_Loaded;
            AssociatedObject.dataPager.OnDemandLoading -= DataPager_OnDemandLoading;
            AssociatedObject.dataGrid.Dispose();
            AssociatedObject.dataPager.Dispose();
        }
```

When I navigate to different UserControls, Events remain open and occupy memory. I want to close UserControl and release the memory. How can I do that?

**Update 1:**

I have used `ContentControl` in the main window to show different UserControls when I'm navigating:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="Pages" Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}" />
```

**Update 2:**

I used the following code in the UserControl code-behind:

```
public EquipmentIdentitySetting()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataPager.Unloaded += DataPager_Unloaded;
    dataGrid.Unloaded += DataGrid_Unloaded;
}
private void DataGrid_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dataGrid = null;
}

private void DataPager_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dataPager = null;
}
```

But the problem did not solve. Every time I navigate to this UserControl, memory usage increases.

Comment: Have you tried the control's `Unloaded` event?

Comment: @Clemens I updated the question. I tried your solution but the memory usage increases every time I navigate to this UserControl.

Comment: I've meant the Unloaded event of the UserControl, i.e. `this.Unloaded += ...`. Not sure if it is called at all.

Comment: @Clemens It has an `Unload` event. What should I write in the implementation?

Comment: Everything that you think should be done when the control is no longer needed.

Comment: When debugging effects of increasing memory consumption, make sure to force a GC collect right before and after your testcase action. Otherwise increased memory consumption doesn't tell you anything apart from "GC doesn't prioritize cleanup right now". How much does the memory usage increase?

Comment: Related: https://michaelscodingspot.com/find-fix-and-avoid-memory-leaks-in-c-net-8-best-practices/